# Como pegar a ultima segunda feira em php

Tags: php

Como pegar sempre a data da ultima segunda-feira em PHP, Por exemplo hoje é terça dia 22/05 (Terça-feira) e o php pega a data 21/05 (Segunda-feira).

Comment: Se hoje fosse segunda-feira, ele deveria mostrar a data de hoje ou a segundas feira anterior?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basta usar o formato [relativo de data](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php):

```
$date = new DateTime("last monday");
```

Que seria a última segunda-feira que passou.

Saída:

```
object(DateTime)#1 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "2018-05-21 00:00:00.000000"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(16) "Europe/Amsterdam"
}
```

Código: https://3v4l.org/25tVY

Comment: Não deu certo, utilizei do mesmo jeito ai e deu erro.

Comment: @DanielAlencarSouza qual erro ocorreu, pois, como pode ver no link, funciona em diversas versões do php (em todas estas: 5.6.0 - 5.6.30, hhvm-3.12.14 - 3.22.0, 7.0.0 - 7.2.4).

Answer (score 2):

Utilize [**date**](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.date.php) para formatar a data de acordo com [**strtotime**](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strtotime.php)  informado

```
 echo date('d/m/Y',strtotime('-1 Monday')); // 21/05/2018

 echo date('d-m-Y',strtotime('-1 Monday')); // 21-05-2018

 echo date('d/m',strtotime('-1 Monday')); // 21-05

 echo date('d-m',strtotime('-1 Monday')); // 21-05
```

[**ideone**](https://ideone.com/leHz9V)

> A função **strtotime** aceita uma string, no formato “US English date”, e realiza um parse nela transformando em um `timestamp`, tornando possivel a soma de datas, obtenção de dias específicos e inúmeras outras funcionalidades.

**Exemplos:**

Ultima segunda-feira `strtotime('-1 Monday');`

Última segunda-feira `strtotime("last Monday");`

Próxima quinta `strtotime("next Thursday");`

Próxima quinta `strtotime("+1 Thursday");`

Penúltima segunda-feira `strtotime('-2 Monday');`

Próxima segunda-feira `strtotime('+1 Monday');`

Pegar a hora agora `strtotime("now");`

Usando uma data textual `strtotime("10 September 2017");`

Adicionar um dia `strtotime("+1 day");`

Adicionar uma semana `strtotime("+1 week");`

Adicionar uma semana, dois dias, quatro horas e dois segundos `strtotime("+1 week 2 days 4 hours 2 seconds");`

Pegar data de hoje e adicionar 10 dias

```
$now = strtotime("now");

strtotime("+10 day",$now);
```